# grails - sum of double data type in exponential value

Tags: postgresql, grails

I have a query that will get the sum of some columns in my postgres database.

```
def total = Funds.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(a.FundA), SUM(a.FundB), SUM(a.FundC), SUM(a.FundA+a.FundB+a.FundC) FROM Funds a")
```

Given that `FundA`, `FundB` and `FundC` is defined as double.

Values: (Sample Only)

```
FundA = 233.343
      = 3.234
      = 324.23423

FundB = 32423.4234
      = 43.434
      = 234.234

FundC = 234.2342
      = 343.4345
      = 23423.3434
```

Query Result:

```
[560.81123, 32701.0914, 24001.0121, 57262.914730000004]
```

The sum of `FundA`, `FundB` and `FundC` is correct but the overall total is not trailing zero's with four at the end is not quite right.

```
Actual Result: 57262.914730000004
Expected Result: 57262.91473
```

How can I get the exact over all sum of the 3 columns? Without rounding off. Thank you

Comment: @doelleri it helps me to understand my problem a little bit. One of the solutions given is to use an exact data type for dealing with money, decimal. I am sure that i already used BigDecimal and the result is the same.

Comment: Is the BigDecimal mapped to a NUMERIC column type on the database?